# I need to make a box in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

```
    protected void texto() {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final EditText input = new EditText(activity);
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        }
    });
}
```

Doesn´t show me the text box on the scene maybe someone knows I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to at it to your `View`. Right now you are instantiating an `EditText` view but is not added to the layout `View` (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) that your screen is rendering, thus making it not appearing.

To solve it, first you need to get your View using `activity.findViewById`, then you add the `EditText` view as a subview to it.
Adjust the position if needed.